# #define and expected primary-expression error

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The following code causes  "expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token" error when trying to compile it on Linux:

```
#define PRINTF(args, ...) printf((args), __VA_ARGS__)

void test( )
{
   PRINTF( "test" );
}
```

The same code works fine on Windows. I am not sure what the problem is.

Solution:

adding ## before `__VA_ARGS__` solves the problem

Comment: `PRINTF( "test" );` expands to `printf(("test"), );`, which has a spurious comma. Smells like an MSVC extension if that works.

Comment: what is a MSVC extension? The use of `__VA_ARGS__`?

Comment: No, the fact that the compiler accepts the broken syntax that results from the expansion.

Comment: 1. You should say which compiler you are using in both cases

Comment: @Quentin actually the attempted macro invocation is a constraint violation (C11 6.10.3/4)

Answer (score 4):

In Standard C, `#define PRINTF(args, ...)` means that any invocation of the `PRINTF` macro must supply at least two arguments.

The GNU preprocessor offers two extensions:

- It is possible to supply one argument in this case, and it will behave as if a second, empty argument had been provided.
- `, ## __VA_ARGS__` is allowed in the expansion with meaning:

  - If the empty argument extension from the previous bullet point is happening, this all expands to nothing (i.e. no trailing comma)
  - Otherwise, it behaves as `, __VA_ARGS__`.

If you see a compiler accept your original code, it means that there is a preprocessor in use that offers non-standard extensions. Conversely, your "solution" might not work on some implementations.

Comment: To be clear, GCC's extension is exactly as non-standard as MSVC's. In either case, choosing that extension means it won't work on at least one other major compiler. (I don't think you're trying to suggest otherwise, but I think it could be made clearer.)

Comment: @hvd I don't know anything about MSVC's preprocessor extensions or lack of them. Also it is not known whether OP used MSVC at any point.

Comment: I do know that this particular extension is one of MSVC's, but regardless, you can pretend I wrote "whichever compiler the OP is using" instead, that doesn't really affect my comment.

Comment: @hvd Which other major compiler doesn't have this extension?